# How to write tests on HTTP client apache?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to write a test for my service that sets up a connection with another service that returns me items from the database. My problem is that I set the connection properties in the test and start the service. How can this be mock or something similar?

My start service method:

```
public void doStartService() {
        super.doStartService();
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager manager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        manager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute);
        manager.setMaxTotal(maxConnections);

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
                .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout)
                .setRedirectsEnabled(false).build();

        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
        builder.setConnectionManager(manager);
        client = builder.build();
    }
```

My setup test method and one test method:

```
private ProductCatalogIntegrationService service;

 @Before
    public void setup() {
        service = new Service();
        service.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        service.setSocketTimeout(10000);
        service.setMaxConnections(10);
        service.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(10);
        service.setUrl("http://localhost:8888/products");
        service.doStartService();
    }


    @Test
    public void testReturnProductById() {
        service.setProductById(GET_PRODUCT_BY_ID); // set url from get product by id, by this url my other service goes to the database
        jsonItem = service.getProductById("1"); //get product by id 1

        assertEquals(jsonItem.getId(), FIRST_PRODUCT_ID); // I compare the id on which I made the request to the database, so that I came and was wrapped in a class wrapper
    }
```

How to do it correctly, so as not to configure the connection in the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Javalin](https://javalin.io/) would be an excellent tool for mocking the real service as it allows for state assertions in your tests.

[Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) can be used as well. But it leads to hard to maintain behavioral tests (verify).